# Problem with converting rosmake package to catkin package

Tags: catkin, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### replace the old CMakeList files with new files, update the layout(thank you dornhege), add the layout with tree command

I'm currently working with a project with two rosmake package.

Both package contains several .cpp files and .h files but there are no main function in any those cpp files, and none of this file have ros functions like ros::initial() blah blah, so they are just ordinary cpp files.

I successfully convert the first package into a catkin package(follow http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild and the catkin 0.6.15 document) then I run the `catkin_make` at my work space. Everything works well, I got a lot of .cpp.o files and a `libmathlib.so` (mathlib is the name of this package) file.

And in the second package, I want to use the first package.  But here comes the problem, I convert the menifest.xml and CMakeList.txt into catkin format file, but as I catkin_make this package

This problem shows up

```
In file included from /home/lc/ros_ws/src/SEDS/src/GMR.cpp:31:0:
/home/lc/ros_ws/src/SEDS/include/GMR.h:28:28: fatal error: mathlib/Mathlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include<mathlib/Mathlib.h>
```

Thank you for your reading, and does any one know how to solve this problem?
If there are any extra information needed for this problem, please tell me.

CmakeLists:
mathlib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mathlib)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
               INCLUDE_DIRS include
               LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(THE_SOURCE_FILES
    src/Differentiator.cpp
    src/GradientDescent.cpp
    src/IKGroupSolver.cpp
    src/IKSubSolver.cpp
    src/Macros.cpp
    src/MathLibCommon.cpp
    src/MathLib.cpp
    src/Matrix3.cpp
    src/Matrix4.cpp
    src/Matrix.cpp
    src/ReferenceFrame.cpp
    src/Regression.cpp
    src/SpatialForce.cpp
    src/SpatialFrame.cpp
    src/SpatialInertia.cpp
    src/SpatialMatrix.cpp
    src/SpatialVector.cpp
    src/SpatialVelocity.cpp
    src/TMatrix.cpp
    src/TVector.cpp
    src/Vector3.cpp
    src/Vector.cpp
    )
   
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${THE_SOURCE_FILES} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)


install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp" PATTERN "*.h")
```

Another package(seds):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(seds)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp mathlib)


include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS mathlib
           DEPENDS roscpp
               INCLUDE_DIRS include
               LIBRARIES seds
)

set(THE_SOURCE_FILES
    src/GMR.cpp
    )


add_library(seds ${THE_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(seds ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS seds
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Layout of mine two packages
mathlib package

```
    .
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── mathlib
    │       ├── Differentiator.h
    │       ├── GradientDescent.h
    │       ├── IKGroupSolver.h
    │       ├── IKSubSolver.h
    │       ├── Macros.h
    │       ├── MathLibCommon.h
    │       ├── MathLib.h
    │       ├── Matrix3.h
    │       ├── Matrix4.h
    │       ├── Matrix.h
    │       ├── ReferenceFrame.h
    │       ├── Regression.h
    │       ├── SpatialForce.h
    │       ├── SpatialFrame.h
    │       ├── SpatialInertia.h
    │       ├── SpatialMatrix.h
    │       ├── SpatialVector.h
    │       ├── SpatialVelocity.h
    │       ├── TMatrix.h
    │       ├── tmp.txt
    │       ├── TVector.h
    │       ├── Vector3.h
    │       └── Vector.h
    ├── package.xml
    └── src
        ├── Differentiator.cpp
        ├── GradientDescent.cpp
        ├── IKGroupSolver.cpp
        ├── IKSubSolver.cpp
        ├── Macros.cpp
        ├── MathLibCommon.cpp
        ├── MathLib.cpp
        ├── Matrix3.cpp
        ├── Matrix4.cpp
        ├── Matrix.cpp
        ├── ReferenceFrame.cpp
        ├── Regression.cpp
        ├── SpatialForce.cpp
        ├── SpatialFrame.cpp
        ├── SpatialInertia.cpp
        ├── SpatialMatrix.cpp
        ├── SpatialVector.cpp
        ├── SpatialVelocity.cpp
        ├── TMatrix.cpp
        ├── TVector.cpp
        ├── Vector3.cpp
        └── Vector.cpp
```

seds package

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── seds
│       └── GMR.h
├── package.xml
└── src
    └── GMR.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220703/problem-with-converting-rosmake-package-to-catkin-package/) by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-10**:
Please add the file layout of the packages and the CMakeLists.txt of both packages.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-10**:
Thank you for your remind I have added those information.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-12**:
You can use the `tree` command to give the actual folder layout. Also remove the header files from cmake, they don't need to be compiled (explicitly) and just clutter up the files.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-12**:
Hi, I have done those changes recommended.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-12**:
I can't see anything wrong right now. Does it work? Have you tried a clean build, i.e., remove build/ devel/?

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-12**:
:(. I remove the build/ and devel/ but unfortunate nothing changed, I still got the same error message. I check the devel/ folder there are no header file from mathlib generated there, I think this is the reason why seds can't find the .h file. Anyway thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a guess, but did you remember to [export your headers and libraries](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html#exporting)?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-10**:
I read this page yesterday, but I'm not 100% sure about whether I use it correctly in mine packages.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-10**:
The `catkin_package()` needs to go after the message generation.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-11**:
I put the catkin_package() element just after include. I think that's what you mean.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-17**:
Maybe not, here is the required overall order: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_overview.html#cmakelists-txt .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're including something from `mathlib/Mathlib.h`, yet your headers seem to be in `include`, not `include/mathlib`. This cannot work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-11-11**:
RIght. Note that it *should* be in `include/mathlib`. You need the extra directory level.

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-11**:
Thank you. I do the change, but still catkin_make says

```
In file included from /home/lc/ros_ws/src/SEDS/src/GMR.cpp:31:0:
/home/lc/ros_ws/src/SEDS/include/GMR.h:28:28: fatal error: mathlib/Mathlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include<mathlib/Mathlib.h>
```

**Comment by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on 2015-11-11**:
But I get the feeling that I'm getting closer to the right answer:)